# Using an interrupt to handle a boolean in arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I've researched a bit, and I've ran into a couple of examples of how buttons are used as interrupts. However, the design I'm trying to implement uses analog sensors. Right now, what I want to do is to have my analog sensors flag a boolean to tell the interrupt to execute, not a button. How would I do so?

This is what I have thought up based on what I researched:

```
    boolean isWall;

    attachInterrupt(isWall, interruptFunction, RISING);

    void loop() {
        if(analogSensor.response > 450) {
                isWall = true;
        }
        normalExecution();  // what it normally does if isWall is false 
    }

    void interruptFunction() {
          // code implementation
          isWall = false;  // set isWall back to false after executing interruptFunction
    }

    void normalExecution() {
          // foo
    }
```

Can someone verify?

Comment: i think i'm suppose to have 'volatile' in front of the boolean declaration

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am completely wrong but it has always been my understanding that interrupts in Arduino are based on the *voltage* seen by a pin - i.e. they are *hardware* interrupts. Consequently, while your code is correct for a hardware interrupt, it will not work for a change in a variable.

That said, this [link](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,17450.0.html) and this [link](http://www.digikey.com/us/en/techzone/microcontroller/resources/articles/arduinos-analog-functions-how-to-use-them.html) discuss **Analog Comparator** methods for accomplishing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, so I guess what I'm trying to look for is something that'll poll my sensors every 10 us in the background, and not whenever response(). And then whenever my sensors reach a certain defined value, it should jump to my interrupt function.